# ImageProcessor throws an exception when I'm trying to convert an image to webp

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, image-processing, webp

I'm learning how to convert images to .webp by reading [this](https://blog.elmah.io/convert-images-to-webp-with-asp-net-core-better-than-png-jpg-files/) article.
Here is my code that is meant to do this:

```cs
public IActionResult ConvertImage(IFormFile file)
{
    var webpFullFilePath = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "imagename.webp");
    using (var webPFileStream = new FileStream(webpFullFilePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (ImageFactory imageFactory = new ImageFactory(preserveExifData: false))
        {
            imageFactory.Load(file.OpenReadStream()) // throws error here
                .Format(new WebPFormat())
                .Quality(100)
                .Save(webPFileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I'm uploading an image it throws an exception:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'ImageProcessor.Plugins.WebP.Imaging.Formats.NativeMethods' threw an exception.
> ---> System.IO.IOException: The file '/home/alex/Documents/sayzim/api/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/ImageProcessor.dll' already exists.
> at System.IO.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(String fullPath)
> at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Create()
> at ImageProcessor.Configuration.NativeBinaryFactory.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.b__0(String b)
> at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
> at ImageProcessor.Configuration.NativeBinaryFactory.RegisterNativeBinary(String name, Byte[] resourceBytes)
> at ImageProcessor.Plugins.WebP.Imaging.Formats.NativeMethods..cctor()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Here is packages that I'm using:

1. `<PackageReference Include="ImageProcessor" Version="2.9.1" />`
2. `<PackageReference Include="ImageProcessor.Plugins.WebP" Version="1.3.0" />`
3. `<PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="4.7.0" />`

How to fix this problem? If you know another way to convert images to .webp, please share it with me :)

**P.S.** I use linux mint.

Comment: were you able to solve it?

Comment: @Jay Don't remember, but now I moved to ImageSharp and SkiaSharp and don't have problems